# conditional uncheck checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

This function works great to check a checkbox, but the else clause  does not uncheck it.

```
  function checkOLR() {
      if (document.getElementById('co_month') !="" || document.getElementById('regfee') !="" || document.getElementById('pp_email') !="") {
               // Check
            document.getElementById("mycheckbox").checked = true;
      } else {
             // Uncheck
            document.getElementById("mycheckbox").checked = false;
      }
   }
```

Each of the three input fields has an onchange='checkOLR' statement. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Is `co_month` an input? You need to use the `value` property of the object if so.

Comment: Running just the actual commands to check and uncheck to box work fine, it must be an error with your if statement

Comment: Show us all the relevant code (the HTML as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the elements you're checking in the `if` statement are inputs, you need to check against the values of these fields (using the `value` attribute of the object). Otherwise, the `if()` statement will always return `true`, since the elements do not equal an empty string.

```
function checkOLR() 
{
    if( document.getElementById('co_month').value != "" || document.getElementById('regfee').value != "" || document.getElementById('pp_email').value != "" ) 
    {
        // Check
        document.getElementById("mycheckbox").checked = true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Uncheck
        document.getElementById("mycheckbox").checked = false;
    }
}
```